# Wortwahl in "In welcher Art von ___ wohnst du jetzt?"

Tags: word-choice

> In welcher Art von ___ wohnst du jetzt? Haus, Wohnung, Studentenwohnheim, oder was?

Welches Wort passt hier am besten? Gehen "Unterkunft" oder "Unterbringung"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abgesehen von "Unterbringung" funktionieren prinzipiell alle. "Unterbringung" referenziert aber eher [die Bereitstellung einer Unterkunft](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unterbringung), nicht die Behausung.

Die tatsächliche Wortwahl passt du natürlich deinem Vorwissen an. Hast du keine Idee, so wählst du "Unterkunft", da dies das allgemeingültigste Wort ist.

Wenn du weißt, dass die Person in eine Wohnung, ein Wohnheim oder Haus gezogen ist, so fragst du konkret nach dessen Art.

---

Angemerkt sei noch, dass in der Umgangssprache auch gerne "In was für einer Art..." anstatt "welcher" gefragt wird.

Comment: Ich würde sagen, dass in Umgangssprache schlicht "Wie wohnst Du jetzt?" gefragt werden würde. :)

Comment: @try-catch-finally... mach 'ne Antwort draus. Das ist mit Abstand das idiomatischste

Comment: Interessant. Ich finde, dass "Wie wohnst du jetzt" alles andere als idiomatisch ist.