# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Wohnung, Apartment, Haus, Zimmer und WG?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich möchte über die Webseite der Universität eine Wohnung mieten. Es gibt hier verschiedene Angebote privater Vermieter, nämlich Wohnung, Apartment, Haus, Zimmer und WG. Worin liegt hier der Unterschied?

Ich verstehe das bisher so:

1. Wohnung, Apartment und Haus sind sich ähnlich. Aber das Haus hat ein Dach und die anderen beiden nicht. Was ist dann der Unterschied zwischen Wohnung und Apartment?
2. Wenn man in einer Wohnung/einem Apartment/Haus wohnt, hat man eine eigene Küche und ein eigenes Badezimmer. Im Vergleich dazu hat man keine eigene Küche/Badezimmer, wenn man nur ein Zimmer mietet oder in einer WG wohnt. Aber gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen Einzelzimmer und WG-Zimmer?

Comment: Hallo Ting, herzlich willkommen bei German.Stackexchange! Ich habe die Rechtschreibung und Grammatik in deiner Frage verbessert und manche Sätze umformuliert, so dass sie für mich als Muttersprachler "natürlicher" klingen. Falls du Fragen zu meinen Veränderungen hast, schreib mir gerne einen Kommentar unter deine Frage!

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/18702/1696).

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ein *Haus* meint ein ganzes Gebäude. Ein Haus kann in mehrere *Wohnungen* unterteilt sein. Normalerweise hat jede Wohnung ein eigenes Bad und eine eigene Küche. Es gibt aber Ausnahmen, zum Beispiel bei sehr kleinen oder sehr alten Wohnungen.

Ein *Apartment* ist im Prinzip dasselbe wie eine Wohnung. Der Begriff wird oft verwendet, um eine Wohnung moderner oder höherwertiger erscheinen zu lassen (und eine höhere Miete zu rechtfertigen).

*WG* ist eine Abkürzung für "Wohngemeinschaft". Das ist eine Gruppe von Personen, die sich ein Haus oder eine Wohnung teilen. In der Regel hat in einer WG jeder ein eigenes Zimmer, andere Räume wie Bad oder Küche werden gemeinsam genutzt.

Der Begriff des *Einzelzimmers* ist nicht so klar definiert. Das kann ein einzelnes Zimmer in einer Wohnung oder einem Haus sein, bei dem Du Dir Bad und Küche mit den anderen Bewohnern teilst, im Prinzip wie bei einer WG. Vielleicht vermietet jemand das ehemalige Kinderzimmer, nachdem das Kind ausgezogen ist. Es kann aber auch eine sehr kleine Wohnung sein. Das musst Du im Einzelfall näher erfragen.

Zwei Hinweise noch, die vielleicht nicht jedem klar sind, der nicht damit aufgewachsen ist: Bei Wohnungen werden normalerweise Räume wie Flur, Küche und Bad nicht mitgezählt. Das heißt, eine "Zwei-Zimmer-Wohnung" besteht typischerweise aus Flur, Küche, Bad plus zwei Zimmern (zum Beispiel ein Wohnzimmer und ein Schlafzimmer).

Und außer der eigentlichen Miete musst Du in der Regel die sogenannten *Nebenkosten* bezahlen. Das umfasst alles außer der Wohnung oder dem Haus selbst, also zum Beispiel Heizkosten, Müllabfuhr, vielleicht ein Hausmeister.

Comment: Ich denke, _Apartment_ impliziert auch, dass es sich um eine möblierte Wohnung handelt. Oder?

Comment: Apartments sind üblicherweise kleiner als Wohnungen, Wikipedia definiert es als "moderne Kleinwohnung". Ob Appartments gehobener sind als Wohnungen ist meines Wissens nach je nach Region anders.

Comment: Achtung, es gibt sowohl Apartment [apa(r)tment] als auch Appartement [apartmɑ̃], und die beiden Wörter heißen nicht dasselbe. (Was genau der Unterschied ist, weiß ich allerdings auch nicht.)

Comment: @sgf Ich sehe da keinen inhaltlichen Unterschied. [Appartement](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Appartement) ist der (ursprünglich) französische Begriff; [Apartment](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Apartment) der englische, der sich ziemlich sicher aus dem französischen entwickelt hat.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Nein, Apartments müssen nicht möbliert sein.

Comment: @Raketenolli Unter deinem Link zu Appartement finde ich zwei Bedeutungen, von denen nur die eine dasselbe ist wie ein Apartment, das andere anscheinend eine Art Suite. Apartment kann nur eine Wohnung sein, nicht eine Suite. Richtig ist also wohl: Die beiden Wörter heißen nicht immer dasselbe.

Comment: Die Heizkosten sind nicht Teil der Nebenkosten und kommen nochmal obendrauf. Kaltmiete + Heiz- **und** Nebenkosten.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist möglicherweise auch regional unterschiedlich. Ich kenne es so, dass die Heizkosten Teil der Nebenkosten sind, aber getrennt abgerechnet werden. In der Regel beauftragt der Vermieter eine spezialisierte Firma damit zu messen, wie viel die Mieter beim Heizen verbrauchen, und das dann abzurechnen. Der Mieterbund [sieht das ähnlich](https://www.mieterbund.de/mietrecht/ueberblick/heizkostenabrechnung.html).